# How can I build a function that would look for 2 certain buttons being clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, button

Salutations,

I am learning to code through some online resources and my brother who works in the field in an effort to get into a development career. Right now I am working on a silly web app where you are **matching photos**. Below each photo is a **button with a unique ID**. Currently, when you select a button, it will turn blue.

I am trying to create a function that will **look for 2 specific buttons being clicked**.

If I were to speak what I want it to do in a conversation with you, I would say "if button1 is select when button4 is selected, do this thing"

What function am I looking for?

Can anyone help this n00b out?

Below I have the function as is for when a button is clicked. The class changes in order to adjust the color.

I can post whatever code is necessary, otherwise this is all I could think to post. {BC1b is a button that should be paired with F1b}

```
  function sbtnb1() {
        document.getElementById("BC1b").className = "selected";
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code here so we can help you out.

Comment: You are looking to keep state which buttons are currently selected, e.g. in multiple boolean variables or better a data structure. Then each time a button is clicked, change its selection state, and check whether the two buttons you are looking for are both selected.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I should've posted my entire code or not. Thank you all for the responses. I am going to try what's been posted below when I get home. Can't wait to get it working!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example.

https://jsfiddle.net/273rhzyw/

With Jquery
https://jsfiddle.net/agoLcuv8/8/

```
   // All buttons with class of button
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".button");

// declare array to keep the match checks
let matchCheckerArray = [];

// Loop through each button and attach an onClick
buttons.forEach(function(button) {
  button.onclick = function() {
    clickHandler(button);
  }
});

const clickHandler = function(button) {
  matchCheckerArray.push(button.dataset.matchId)
  console.log(matchCheckerArray);
  if (matchCheckerArray.length == 2) {
    if (isMatch()) {
      alert('Match');
    }
    matchCheckerArray = [];
    return;
  }
}

const isMatch = function() {
  if (matchCheckerArray[0] === matchCheckerArray[1]) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would keep two global variables (or an array/set of variables) that store what's been clicked. You can manipulate these however you'd like (e.g. clear out the selection if the user selected two photos that aren't a match; don't let the user select a second card if it doesn't match; etc...).

This can work in conjunction with what you already have. The class name will allow you to add specific selected styling, while the global variables allow you to keep track of what has been selected. The global variables will also allow you to check for match or no match.

Comment: Thanks, Tim! Looking forward to trying this when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this but this is how I would go about it.

```js
$(".checkButton").on("click", function(){

  // toggle button state
  if($(this).attr("data-state") == "on") {
    $(this).attr("data-state", "off");  // toggle button off
    $(this).removeClass("highlight"); // remove highlight
    $(".myImage").removeClass("highlight"); // remove highlight
  } else {
    $(this).attr("data-state", "on"); // make button active
    $(this).addClass("highlight"); // add highlight
  }
  
  //----------------------------------------------------------
  // Here you would have to build your checks and how you want
  // the comparison of buttons and images to be linked.
  //----------------------------------------------------------
  // For example:
  // check if more than 2 buttons are active and if buttons match the if statement.
  var buttonCount = 0;
  
  $("#buttonContainer button").each(function(){    
    if($(this).attr("data-state") == "on"){
      buttonCount += 1;
    }    
  });
  
  
  // if 2 buttons are clicked then check then allow to do something
  if(buttonCount == 2){
    
    // highlight image 1 if buttons 1 and 2 are on.  
    if($(".checkButton[data-id=b1]").attr("data-state") == "on" &&
       $(".checkButton[data-id=b2]").attr("data-state") == "on"){        
        $("#image1").addClass("highlight");       
    }
    
      // highlight image 2 if buttons 3 and 4 are on.  
    if($(".checkButton[data-id=b3]").attr("data-state") == "on" &&
       $(".checkButton[data-id=b4]").attr("data-state") == "on"){        
        $("#image2").addClass("highlight");       
    }
    
  }
  
  //----------------------------------------------------------
  
});
```

```css
.myImage {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
  background: black;
  float: left;
}

.highlight {
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 110px;">
  <div class="myImage" id="image1"></div>
  <div class="myImage" id="image2"></div>
</div>

<div id="buttonContainer" style="width: 100%;">
  <button class='checkButton' data-id="b1" data-state='off'>button 1</button>
  <button class='checkButton' data-id="b2" data-state='off'>button 2</button>
  <button class='checkButton' data-id="b3" data-state='off'>button 3</button>
  <button class='checkButton' data-id="b4" data-state='off'>button 4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the quick help!